# ApplicationRequestRouting can't connect to URL but the server's browser can

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module, windows-server-2019, arr

I use ApplicationRequestRouting and UrlRewrite v7.1.1980 in IIS to create a reverse-proxy to our backend, but it returns 502.3 Bad Gateway:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
        <EventID>0</EventID>
        <Version>1</Version>
        <Level>3</Level>
        <Opcode>16</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-10-24T10:16:29.431Z"/>
        <Correlation ActivityID="{80000011-0002-F900-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
        <Execution ProcessID="6684" ThreadID="4080"/>
        <Computer>Computer1</Computer>
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name="ContextId">{80000011-0002-F900-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
        <Data Name="ModuleName">ApplicationRequestRouting</Data>
        <Data Name="Notification">128</Data>
        <Data Name="HttpStatus">502</Data>
        <Data Name="HttpReason">Bad Gateway</Data>
        <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">3</Data>
        <Data Name="ErrorCode">2147954429</Data>
        <Data Name="ConfigExceptionInfo"/>
    </EventData>
    <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
        <Opcode>MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS</Opcode>
        <Keywords>
            <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
        </Keywords>
        <freb:Description Data="Notification">EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER</freb:Description>
    </RenderingInfo>
    <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
        <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
    </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

However, when I log into the server with Remote Desktop and open our URL in the server's browser, it opens fine - so there is connectivity between our server and backend.

How can the browser "see" the URL but IIS claims it has no connection?

Comment: The error information doesn't show the key factor that lead to this 502.3 error, you can try to enable failed request tracing, it will provide the key error and warning, this link provide the method to enable failed request tracing to capture the detailed error: [Using Failed Request Tracing Rules to Troubleshoot Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the issue. Inside of our ARR Cache config we had added a proxy server which had stopped responding. After removing the proxy server, it works again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community member in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.